# Transforming list to dict with list items as keys and list indices as values in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to transform

```
l = ['a','b','c','d']
```

to

```
d = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
```

The best solution I have so far is that one:

```
d = {l[i]:i for i in range(len(l))}
```

Is there more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
d = {e:i for i, e in enumerate(l)}
```

*Edit:* As @LeonYoung suggested, if you want to be compatible with python < 2.7 (despite the tag), you must use

```
d = dict((e, i) for i, e in enumerate(l))
```

Comment: Good, but not perfect. Only python 2.7+ supports dictionary comprehension. I suppose you'd like use `d = dict((e, i) for i, e in enumerate(l))` to adapt earlier version of python.

Comment: @LeonYoung, but the question is tagged for 2.7

Comment: @LeonYoung: good point, thanks. I'm using py3 primarily, and tend to forget about the stuff before 2.7.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution. I'll wait some time for other solutions and, if there are no any, mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

With `itertools`, just for fun

```
>>> from itertools import count, izip
>>> L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> dict(izip(L, count()))
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 3}
```